# PC stuck when start the MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using mySql workbench 6.2CE and I was using it for more than 3 months.
Suddenly when I start it few days back, it opened the workbench but my pc got stuck (Windows 8.1). Ans still the problem is same, can't open the workbench as it causes my PC to restart to work.

My PC configuration is intel core i7 (3.4Ghz) and 8GB memory (HP workstation).

Is there any setting that I can include to its start up like memory setting or any other solution?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @Dwza Thanks, I saw couple of questions posted related to Workbench issues in stackoverflow. So thought I also could get some help.

Comment: Perhaps you get help here but you probably have better results and more activity for this question at Super User. Is the same as SO.

Comment: @Dwza Thanks pal, I will post it there too.